Elementor Cards on Wordpress not retaining line breaks
I have written posts on Wordpress, and I want excerpts of them to appear in "Cards" (using Elementor) on my webpage, that are then opened to the full post. However in the post the excerpt starts with "The problem" on a separate line and then gets into the rest of the content. On the card "The problem" is on the same line as the following content and it looks (and sounds) weird to a reader. How can I retain the line break?

If you want to retain line breaks without manually editing each excerpt, you can modify WordPress to allow HTML in excerpts by adding a code snippet to your theme’s functions.php file:
function allow_html_in_excerpt($excerpt) {
    return wpautop($excerpt); // Converts line breaks into HTML <p> tags
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'allow_html_in_excerpt');

